# How to distribute storyboard view?

Tags: ios, storyboard, apple-watch

I’m creating an open source plugin for a developer to use a custom screen in their Apple Watch Extension and want them to add it to their storyboard. How can I package it and instructing them to included in their application (storyboard)?

Maybe something like the include tag in Android ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use one single Storyboard in an Apple Watch app, so if you have done UI in IB then you will have to copy the `InterfaceController` (You didn't make a UIViewController right?) that you made to their Storyboard.

If what you did was all programmatically generated, which i haven't tried yet, you can give them your `.m` and `.h` file and they can include it to their project, and then instantiate a new `InterfaceController` of that class.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into that, it looks like you can't add view programmatically yet in WatchKit.

Comment: I would say send them a new storyboard with your view and have them copy paste the scene to their watch storyboard, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate xib file or just add your storyboard containing just the one view controller to the project. The implementers can then instantiate the view controller using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the tags to mention that it's for Apple Watch. Do you think it's possible for Apple Watch?

Comment: Ah ok. I don't know actually. Haven't developed anything for the Apple Watch yet.